# Registering Plugins with ES6 Modules into webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules, webpack-2

So currently I have a SPA that includes different capabilities based on 'plugins' that can be installed (by users). This app is mainly TypeScript currently, and the JS files that are output (es5 syntax with no loader), are just included via script tag into the SPA landing page. This has worked well enough, but now the no. of scripts is large for certain users, so I am planning to webpack (TS -> ES6 -> Babel -> Webpack Bundle) the plugins, however I can see a way to easily load certain code only or certain users.

So the main app.ts looks something like this

```
module MyApp {
  export class App() {
  }

  export Plugins {
    export class PageEditor extends Plugin { ... }
  }
}
window['MyApp'] = MyApp;
```

And say the TicketPlugin.ts looks like this

```
module MyApp {
  export Plugins {
    export class TicketManager extends Plugin { ... }
  }
}
```

And now to generate the menu I simply do this:

```
var MenuItems = Object.keys(MyApp.Plugins).map(p=>MyApp.Plugins[p].menuItem());
```

**Now the main problem i am encountering**

The obvious way to restore the functionality is to make each plugin an entry point, and then include a script tag for each plugin that is required (but that is no improvement over where i am now).

Ideally I would like to pack the plugins, output them into separate files, and the server can then concatenate them to the bundle depending on what plugins the current user requires. However i cant see a way of having these files run to register themselves, either with another class/component or as a global.

I have seen the way webpack handles jQuery Plugins, but you have to know before you webpack the app, what jquery plugins you are planning to load, and require them.